# Efficiently coding gradient of function

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently trying to code this beastie in Python (using the numpy libraries). The lambda `* w` is supposed to be outside the summation.

Currently, I've coded the problem using a for loop, and a running total outside; however, this approach takes a long time.
My vectors for `y`, `w`, and `x` are very large - think 100,000s of elements. I was wondering whether there is a simpler way to vectorize the element instead using simple matrix operations instead of looping through the vector one element by another element.

This is my vectorized code:

```
xty = xtrain.T.dot(ytrain)
e = math.exp(-w_0.T.dot(xty))
gradient = (-xty*(e/1+e)-lambda_var*w_0)
```

[image: gradient]

Comment: Share your loopy code? Also, please add minimal sample representative relevant inputs, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you might just have to bite the bullet and go with the loop:

```
import numpy as np
wave = 1e3
xs, ys, w = np.arange(1, 4), np.arange(4, 7), np.arange(7, 10)
eps = np.zeros(w.T.shape)
for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    eps += -y * np.exp(-y * w.T * x) * x / (1 + np.exp(-y * w.T * x))
print(eps + wave * w)

[ 7000.  8000.  9000.]
```